# Android app crashing

Tags: android, logging

My new Android app is crashing when I run it on my phone, but never in the emulator.
Can someone tell me where the logs are generated on the phone so perhaps I can get to the bottom of this thing?

Many thanks, Victor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also look up an app on the market named [alogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat). Search for your app with that app (Menu>Search).

Answer (score 3):

You can connect your phone to your computer and debug with Logcat. In your phone, just enable

Menu->Setting->Application->Development->Usb debugging

From your windows/linuxmac console

```
adb devices
adb -s device_serial logcat
```

There are your log.

Answer (score 2):

```
Windows --> Open Perspective -->other -->DDMS-->OK (Select your Device)
```

**And for USB Debugging in device**

```
Menu-->Setting->Application-->Development-->Usb Debugging
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the crash logs use the [Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html).